# JQuery: how to get the value of an ID from Master/Content page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, master-pages

i have this in my content page: but i am getting null value if  i try  `$("#ctl00_cphMaster_CloseButton").`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ctl00_cphMaster_CloseButton").click(function() {
            jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
                if (r == true)
                    __doPostBack('CloseButton', '');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});

<uc1:ImageTextButton ID="CloseButton" runat="server" 
            ImageURL="Images/closeIcon.png"
            Enabled="True" Text="Close" 
            CausesValidation="false" onclick="CloseButton_Click" />
```

UPDATE:

i have tried like this:

```
$("#<%= CloseButton.ClientID %>").click(function() {

        jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
            if (r == true)
                __doPostBack('CloseButton', '');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

when i run my page it throws me an error with this code:

```
$("#ctl00_cphMaster_CloseButton").click(function() {

        jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
            if (r == true)
                __doPostBack('CloseButton', '');
        });
        return false;
    });
```

it means it got the right id but why is it throwing an error complaining about null

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object**

UPDATE:

KP Suggestion:

```
$("#<%= CloseButton.ClientID %>").click(function() { 
             alert("yes");
       }); 
});
```

Comment: I'd try testing in Firefox with Firebug. You'll get a much more meaningful error message. IE jscript error messages are terrible.

Comment: Can you remove the contents of the click function, and just do an `alert('button clicked');` call. You want to make sure first the click handler is working, and then determine if the null error is your code within. This might not have anything to do with the wrong ID, etc.

Comment: @KP: i did tried your suggestions but i never hit the alert, i update my question please have a look at it. if thats what you mean.

Comment: you need to use developer tools in your browser to find out what's going on. From your update you can clearly see that the issue is not about the id, so there is something weird going on as to why the element is not on the page when .ready is reached. Use whichever tool you have available in the browser you are using / in firefox use firebug, and chrome and IE8 have their own too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with $("[id$=CloseButton]") which matches elements which end with CloseButton

Comment: run $("[id$=CloseButton]") in firebug, if the console displays the element as found, then the problem is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: i tried in VisualStudio Qucikwatch and it returns me "null" and also tried in immedidate window same thing.

Comment: I think the simplest solution I can give you is to load the proyect in firefox, with firebug, and inspect the element to find out what the ID of your control is, and build your selector around that. You can also just look at the source for the page and find the ID there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(VS.71).aspx)-Property of the button-control?

```
$("#<%= CloseButton.ClientID %>")
```